# Preventing Long-Running Tables From Clipping Header Image

Tags: java, xsl-fo

I'm creating an XSL-FO document in Java. It contains a long table with multiple cells that can, at times, run multiple pages.  When it does, it causes the table to clip into an image in our header at the top.

What type of padding do I need to add to prevent our table from clipping into a header image when the clipping occurs mid-table?

We cannot move the header up or down because it is a legal document.

Edit: I'll do my best to include the code from the app, though I'll have to edit it down a bit.

This is our header:

```
  w.write("<fo:static-content flow-name=\"xsl-region-before\">");
  w.write("<fo:block-container height=\"1.01in\" width=\"7in\" padding-bottom=\".1in\">");
  w.write("<fo:table table-layout=\"fixed\"  width=\"7in\">");
  w.write("<fo:table-column column-width=\"2.4cm\"/><fo:table-column column-width=\"14cm\"/>");
  w.write("<fo:table-body>");
  w.write("<fo:table-row>");
  w.write("<fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned=\"2\">");
  w.write("<fo:block padding-left=\"4mm\">");
  w.write("<fo:external-graphic top=\"0cm\" src=\"url('"+this.getResourceUrl("Url.tif")+"')\" width=\"2.4cm\"/>");
  w.write("</fo:block>");
  w.write("</fo:table-cell>");
  w.write("<fo:table-cell>");
  w.write("<fo:block font-size=\"10pt\" padding-top=\"4mm\" text-align=\"left\"><fo:inline font-weight=\"bold\">");
  w.filteredWrite("SomeCompany");
  w.write("</fo:inline></fo:block>");
  w.write("<fo:block font-size=\"10pt\" padding-top=\"1mm\" text-align=\"left\"><fo:inline font-weight=\"bold\">");
  w.filteredWrite(this.getStuff());
  w.write(",</fo:inline> Stuff");
  w.write("</fo:block>");
  w.write("<fo:block font-size=\"10pt\" padding-top=\"1mm\" padding-bottom=\"1mm\" text-align=\"left\"><fo:inline font-weight=\"bold\">");
  w.filteredWrite(this.getAThing());
  w.write(",</fo:inline> ");
  if (this.getAVariable() != null && this.getAVariableLength().length() > 0)
  {
  w.write(this.getAVariable());
  }
  else
  {
  w.write("TEXT");
  }
  w.write("</fo:block>");
  w.write("</fo:table-cell>");
  w.write("</fo:table-row>");

  w.write("<fo:table-row>");

  w.write("<fo:table-cell border-top-style=\"solid\" border-top-color=\"#000000\" border-top-width=\"0.2mm\" >");

  w.write("</fo:table-cell>");
  w.write("</fo:table-row>");
  w.write("</fo:table-body>");
  w.write("</fo:table>");
  w.write("</fo:block-container>");
  w.write("</fo:static-content>");      
}
```

This is what the initial declaration of our table looks like:

```
  w.write("<fo:table table-layout=\"fixed\" width=\"176mm\">");
  w.write("<fo:table-column column-width=\"38mm\"/><fo:table-column column-width=\"38mm\"/>");
  w.write("<fo:table-column column-width=\"28mm\"/><fo:table-column column-width=\"27mm\"/>");

  w.write("<fo:table-column column-width=\"25mm\"/>");
  w.write("<fo:table-column column-width=\"20mm\"/>");
```

This is what the table header looks like:

```
  w.write("<fo:table-header>");
  w.write("<fo:table-row background-color=\"black\" color=\"white\" padding=\"2px\" border-width=\"0.2mm\">");
  w.write("<fo:table-cell padding=\"inherit\" border-right-style=\"solid\" border-right-color=\"#000000\" border-right-width=\"0.2mm\">");
  w.write("<fo:block text-align=\"left\" font-size=\"10pt\" color=\"white\" font-weight=\"bold\" font-family=\""+font+"\">NameOfColumn</fo:block>");
  w.write("</fo:table-cell>");
-Four Additional identical sets of cells-
                 }
  w.write("</fo:table-row>");
  w.write("</fo:table-header>");
  w.write("<fo:table-body>");
```

And this is what each additional row looks like when it is initially declared:

```
  w.write("<fo:table-row keep-together=\"always\" padding=\"2px\">");
  w.write("<fo:table-cell padding=\"inherit\"  number-rows-spanned=" + rowsToSpan+" border-right-style=\"solid\" border-right-color=\"#000000\" border-right-width=\"0.2mm\" border-left-style=\"solid\" border-left-color=\"#000000\" border-left-width=\"0.2mm\"  border-bottom-style=\"solid\" border-bottom-color=\"#000000\" border-bottom-width=\"0.2mm\">");
  w.write("<fo:block text-align=\"left\" font-size=\"10pt\" font-family=\""+font+"\">");
```

Comment: Without posting sample code in XSL FO no one can help you.

Comment: @KevinBrown Examples added, though I had to format it a bit to remove direct references to my work, and separate it since the document doesn't follow a direct flow.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to make this work - I simply need to extend the top margin for the Body of my main page master so that the header doesn't overlap my text.

```
 w.write("<fo:simple-page-master master-name=\"main-master\" ");    
 w.write("page-height=\"11in\" page-width=\"8.5in\" margin-top=\".5in\" ");
 w.write("margin-bottom=\".5in\" margin-left=\".5in\" margin-right=\".5in\">"); 
 //w.write("<fo:region-body margin-top=\"20mm\" margin-bottom=\"4in\"/>");
 w.write("<fo:region-body margin-top=\"25mm\" margin-bottom=\"4in\"/>");
```

This means that the top of the page will have a small space between the start of the body and the header, but this is an acceptable compromise for me.